# CSS @import does not work for @media stylesheets

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I tried to include @mesia CSS stylesheet with this:

`@import url("rwd.css");`

I placed it at the end of main CSS stylesheet code but it worked completely different than it should. Any other stylesheets works fine when are imported this way but not @media containing ones.

Is there any way to import CSS stylesheet without putting another tag

`<link href="css/rwd.css" rel="stylesheet">`

in HTML? There is my snippet:

```css
#menu {
  background-color: #eee;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#mobile-menu-button {
  display:none;
}

@import url('rwd.css');

/* @media (max-width:700px) {
  
  h1 {
    font-size: 16px; // that works
  }
  #menu {
    display: none; // that works too!
  }
  #mobile-menu-button {
    display: block; // that does not ps. removing float either
  }
  
} */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="main-style-sheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="mobile-menu-button">show menu</div>
<div id="menu">Menu buttons</div>

<h1>Title</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't just combine/merge the files into one CSS sheet?

Comment: i have different layouts in my project, my css file is large already, besides it is more convinient to work on code with two windows open.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Quentin's well written answer

A simple work-around would be to request your media query file first, and at the top of that, add the @import of your main style sheet

Use this one only in the `<head>`

```
<link href="css/rwd.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And like this in its file

```
@import url('main.css');

@media (max-width:700px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  /* and so on  */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've misidentified the problem.

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import):

> The @import CSS at-rule is used to import style rules from other style sheets. **These rules must precede all other types of rules**, except @charset rules; as it is not a nested statement, @import cannot be used inside conditional group at-rules.

The media query has nothing to do with this failing. It doesn't work because you put `@import` at the end of your stylesheet instead of the start.

---

When I constructed a test case, the rwd.css was not requested from the server until I moved the @import to the top of the CSS file. At that point everything worked (although the change in order meant that some rules were overridden by the later styles in main-style-sheet.css).